# Would questions about beekeeping and colonising be on topic, and desired, here?

Tags: discussion, scope

There's a [Beekeeping](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/95988/beekeeping) proposal which has a good amount of activity, including 61 followers and 67 questions. It has been growing steadily, so I definitely don't think it falls into the criteria for closure. The scope is a bit of a work in progress, as you'll see if you look at the discussion questions, but at the moment it is:

> Proposed Q&A site for anyone interested in caring for, maintaining, learning, making hives, or starting a colony of bees.

There's also a [Colonising](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/102165/colonising) proposal. It has 4 followers and 13 example questions, and no activity in the past 24 days, so I think it's more in jeopardy. There's a discussion about a merger with beekeeping, but it hasn't happened, at least not yet.

Their current scope is:

> Proposed Q&A site for beekeepers, wasp and termite experts, and ant enthusiasts. Anyone interested in creating and maintaining colonies, or simply moving them to other locations.

(There used to be a proposal specifically about ants, which looked interesting, but it must have been deleted.)

It seems like a number of questions from those proposals, though of course not all, would fit into our scope, under the category of "people who love outdoor activities."

I absolutely don't want to interfere with a proposal, and I don't even know etiquette regarding that. I'm just wondering if anyone here thinks branching out into those areas would be on-topic and of interest to our community.

Comment: I'm trying to think how this would differ from questions about cattle ranching or farming in general.  Not making a judgment yet, just asking a question.

Comment: @ab2 Thanks for the comment and for taking some time to think about it. Your point is well taken. As Rory Alsop said, this wouldn't really be within the scope of our site, unless, as he also said, some questions could end up being migrated here.

Comment: Biology has a tag insects.  I think that is a better fit than TGO.

Comment: While I don't see any existing questions there, I believe bee keeping would be in scope at [Sustainability Living](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it grows and launches successfully, which I think a beekeeping site may, then that's brilliant.

I'm not sure we would ever want to merge that into our scope, as the majority of beekeeping interests are specific to beekeeping. Yes, it is outdoors, but it's not about being outdoors, it's about bees.

Once it is live there may be questions that appear there that should be migrated to us - and that is fine. We can always do that.

Comment: "Yes, it is outdoors" or at least, if it isn't, something has gone very, very wrong.